# Removing trailing whitespace with awk

Tags: macos, awk, newline, whitespace, trim

I'm trying to get and print some system information off my Mac using the [system_profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html) command. I'm able to get the information just fine but for each item there's a leading space and trailing newline (I think). The problem is the trailing newline (or whatever's there). Here's an example of one of the commands I'm using:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk -F: '/Processor Speed/ {gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \n]+$/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

Here's the result:

```
2.5 GHz
```

It doesn't show up here but there's some sort of character on the end that causes a newline. The gsub that I have above correctly removes the space at the beginning of the result but I've tried everything I can think of to remove the newline but nothing's worked.

To see the newlines in action, run `system_profiler > output` from the terminal and open the output file in your favourite text editor and show invisible characters.

What I'm ultimately trying to do with this information I'm grabbing is print my basic computer information using a [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html) snippet. I have all of the snippets set up and running correctly but I'm having problems with the newline characters as explained above.

Here's the output currently:

```
Model:  MacBookPro9,2

OS Version: Mac OS X
 10.8.3
 (12D78
)
Processor:  2.5 GHz
  Intel Core i5

Graphics:  Intel HD Graphics 4000
  512 MB

Storage:  APPLE SSD SM128E Media

Memory:  8 GB
```

And here's what I want it to look like:

```
Model: MacBookPro9,2
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.8.3 (12D78)
Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000 512 MB
Storage: APPLE SSD SM128E
Memory: 8 GB
```

TextExpander allows you to run any shell script so if there's any other way I can get the functionality I want I'll gladly use it. (i.e. I've done some searches and I've seen `sed` mentioned among other things but I really don't know anything about shell scripting).

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | tr -dc '[:print:]\n' | awk ...` to delete all unprintable characters in the data.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me. I still have the leading space and the newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` adds a newline.

Use `printf`, instead, if you don't want the newline:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk -F: '/Processor Speed/ {
    gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \n]+$/, "", $2)
    printf "%s", $2
}'
```

---

> It doesn't show up here but there's some sort of character on the end that causes a newline.

To demonstrate things like this, I use `cat -vet`, *viz*:

```
% system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk -F: '/Processor Speed/ {gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \n]+$/, "", $2); print $2}' | cat -vet
2.13 GHz$
```

Comment: Fantastic! That's great. I guess the gsub _was_ working correctly, I was just adding the newline during the print! Really great to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different Field Separator to get rid of the leading space:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk -F': ' '/Processor Speed/{print $2}'
```